# Plot title with variable value and subscript characters in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I'm trying to have a plot title which contains variable values and also characters with subscripts, however when I try:

```
title = "ηₛ = $η̂[Pa S] , μₛ = $μ̂[Pa], μₚ = $μ̂ₚ[Pa] , ηₚ = $η̂ₚ[Pa S] \n α = $α̂ , ζ = $ζ̂"
```

Inside the plot function, the title appears with X marks where the subscripts are. I tried to use LaTeX ```title = L" .." but then the variable values don't appear.
Is there any way to have both in the title I need?

Comment: It works ok here (Julia 1.8.0, Plots 1.29). You could update the installation; or you could try setting the titlefont in your plot statement with `titlefont = "Julia Mono"` or whatever font you know has the unicode characters you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a fully working solution this is what I think you need to do, note that `%$` is used for interpolation:

```
title = L"\eta_1 = %$(η̂[Pa, S])"
```

The reason is that, while some of the characters will be rendered correctly as Bill noted, not all of them will unless you use LaTeXStrings.jl.

See:

```
help?> LaTeXStrings.@L_str
  L"..."

  Creates a LaTeXString and is equivalent to latexstring(raw"..."), except that %$ can be used for interpolation.

  julia> L"x = \sqrt{2}"
  L"$x = \sqrt{2}$"

  julia> L"x = %$(sqrt(2))"
  L"$x = 1.4142135623730951$"
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you add how to treat the new line command too? ```\n``` wouldn't render in Latex mode

Comment: I could not find a single consistent recipe that I could recommend for you that would always work. For some reason Plots.jl does not recognize all LaTeX commands correctly. I suggest you open an issue on Plots.jl and maybe some of its developers will know details of the rules they use.